# Problem with do while loop in JavaSE

Tags: java, do-while

i'm new to programming so consider me a great newbie.
Dilemma:
I want to repeat my code each time I respond to Yes.
I do use the "do while loop" because a statement comes first and the boolean condition should be evaluated at last.

The code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class whysoserious {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
        String go = YES;

        int setone = 0;
        int settwo = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");

        setone = sc.nextInt();
        settwo = sc.nextInt();
        int set = setone + settwo;


        System.out.println("What is " +setone+ " + " +settwo+ " ? ");
        int putone = 0;
        putone = sc.nextInt();

        if (putone == set) 
            System.out.println("Correct!");

        else
            System.out.println("Wrong Answer - The correct answer is: "+set+"");

        System.out.println("Continue?");
        cont = sc.nextLine();
        } while (cont == go);
    }
}
```

**I was asked to add CMD-prompt line.**

- C:\test>javac whysoserious.java
  whysoserious.java:15: cannot find
  symbol symbol  : variable YES
  location: class whysoserious
                 String go = YES;
                             ^ whysoserious.java:38: cannot find
  symbol symbol  : variable cont
  location: class whysoserious
                 cont = sc.nextLine();
                 ^ whysoserious.java:39: cannot find
  symbol symbol  : variable cont
  location: class whysoserious
                 } while (cont == go);
                          ^ whysoserious.java:39: cannot find
  symbol symbol  : variable go
  location: class whysoserious
                 } while (cont == go);
                                  ^ 4 errors

I always get an error each time I try to compile it. The knowledge behind this is that I want to repeat the code every time the user enters Yes or No to continue. Observe that the code works without the do {. At this point, i'm stuck with the do while.

Comment: Please give us the error. Errors are not just to clutter up your screen, they are for trouble-shooting. :)

Comment: Your code will work fine without this but Java style guidelines state that classes should start with a capital letter and classes, variables, and methods should all be camel cased.  So your class should be named "WhySoSerious".

Answer (score 7):

Multiple problems:

- you never declare `cont` or `YES` so the compiler doesn't know what they are
- you declare `go` within the loop, so its out of scope in the `while` expression
- comparing strings with `==` doesn't do what you need here -- you might have two different strings with the same contents.  Use `equals` instead.

The error messages from the compiler should tell you about the first two -- pay attention to what the compiler is saying.

easiest fix:  add `String cont;` before `do`, get rid of `go` and make the test `while ("YES".equals(cont));`  This will still exit if the user enters "yes" or "Y" or " YES" or some other variation, however.

Comment: There are two more: @Racket you have three closing brackets, instead of 2 and the other one is already in @Ronnie's answer.

Answer (score 3):

The line:

```
 String go = YES;
```

should read:

```
String go = "YES";
```

Otherwise, the compiler will think that YES is some variable that it doesn't know about, and proceed to freak out.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @Ronnie Howell stated... use the `equals()` method for String equality.

```
while (cont == go);
```

should read...

```
while (cont.equals(go));
```

PS...I don't see where you've defined `cont`. Please declare it outside the `do` loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WhySoSerious {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cont;
        String go = "YES";

        do {

            System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");

            int setone = sc.nextInt();
            int settwo = sc.nextInt();
            int set = setone + settwo;


            System.out.println("What is " + setone + " + " + settwo + " ? ");
            int putone = sc.nextInt();

            if (putone == set)
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            else
                System.out.println("Wrong Answer - The correct answer is: " + set + "");
            System.out.println("Continue?");
            cont = sc.next();
        } while (cont.equalsIgnoreCase(go));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have a question though. Why doesn't it work if I put sc.nextLine() instead of sc.next()? what's the difference?

Comment: public String next():

Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner.

--------------------------------------------------------------------
public String nextLine():

Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped. This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any line separator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the next line.